# Thinking of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When I think of a group, I can't help but thinking of a function...But those are two different things.

How can I ''view'' a group? For example, what kind of group could the natural log be?

A group consisting of the set of positive reals under some operation? What kind of relations would be in this group?

Or am I thinking it backward?

Comment: You just said that they are different things. Why should the natural log be any kind of group at all?

Comment: I think of groups as pizza pies.

Comment: I think the OP is thinking of $\log$ as a group homomorphism, namely $\log:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ giving a homomorphism $((0,\infty),\times)$ to $(\mathbb R,+)$.

Answer (score 1):

All the data of a group $G$ is encoded in the function
$$\mu : G\times G\rightarrow G$$
Which should be thought of as the group operation, and which satisfies the group axioms. In this way, a group can be thought of as a function.

You might also be interested in reading about formal groups, which is essentially just the group operation without a set. (see the wikipedia article).

I don't see any way of seeing the natural log as a group. However, you can think of it as a group homomorphism from the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^\times$ to the additive group $\mathbb{R}^+$. This follows from the simple identity $\ln ab = \ln a + \ln b$.

If you want to think of the set of the positive reals under an operation, as a group the natural operation would be multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, see a group as a *set* of functions. More precisely, as a set of *permutations* (recall that a permutation is a bijection of a set onto itself). Indeed, if $G$ is a group with operation $\cdot$, an element $a$ of $G$ can be viewed as the function from $G$ to $G$ which sends $x$ to $a\cdot x$ (show that it is a bijection!). This is in particular why the element $e$ such that $e\cdot x = x\cdot e = x$ for all $x$ is sometimes called the *identity*, because when you view it as a function, it is the identity function.